# Is it possible to remove the port from the origin of an ajax get request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm trying to set up a site to access CORS-enabled data on my server. My server has an `access-control-allow-origin` header of `www.mysite.com`, while the request is coming from a source with an origin header of `www.mysite.com:444`. The request is a GET request that's trying to fetch some data from my server, which has been set up to serve data to a portion of my app running in an iframe elsewhere on the site.

This request is getting blocked, unfortunately. How can I successfully make this request? Is there a way for me to take the port number off of my `origin` header, or do I need to modify the `access-control-allow-origin` header on my server? (And if that's the case, how should I go about doing so?)

Comment: Port is part of the "domain" in this context. The host and port parts must match exactly (or have a wildcard).

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit that header on the client side, that would defeat the point of this security header.

Why not just allow www.mysite.com:444 fully on the server ?

Comment: I figured I could do something like that, but I'm honestly not that familiar with server side code. Someone else generally handles that, but they've gone home for the weekend. Can I use a wildcard (i.e. `www.mysite.com*`) on the server to allow both?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't wildcard JUST the port :(  and wildcarding the whole domain is not good either.

Allowing http://www.example.com:444 plus any other port that might come up in the future seems fair.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this on the server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com:444
```